# Redis compare and set atomic

Tags: java, redis, nosql, semaphore, amazon-elasticache

I want to store in redis some int that will show the current load(pending request count).

I need this counter in redis to check if app should send request to underline service or not.

For example I have threshold 50 pending request. And if app already sent 50 request I have to throttle my request. Something similar to distributed semaphore.

I see that Redis has transaction. But it cannot return the value.

Can Redis help me with such case?

Comment: You mean you would like to Atomically "compare the value and increment it by 1" or "compare the value and set a new value"?

Comment: Yeap. Compare and set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a similar requirement where we had to "Compare a value and increment it by 1" Atomically. We ended up using [LUA script](https://redis.io/commands/eval).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36441734/1925997) maybe similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, will try it!